# How can I store a string and two parallel arraylists in an object. (java)

Tags: java

Hi everyone I asked the following a few days ago and am still having a bit of trouble.

**"The following is the original post"**
I want to store a student name  and for each name have two ArrayLists associated with that name. I would like to have it all in one class Student_quizes or something along those lines

so im basicly trying to store studentName, quizNames arraylist and quizScores arraylist in an object. quizNames and quizScores will be parallel.

I am not sure if im going about this the right way at all Ive been trying this all day and am quite confused, Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could better do this.

Im sorry if my question is confusing, I imagine the program would run like this.

> input student name
>
> michael
>
> input quiz
>
> science
>
> input quiz score
>
> 80
>
> add another quiz Y/N?
>
> Y
>
> input quiz ...
>
> add another student Y/N?
>
> Y
>   ...
>
> Student name : michael
>
> quiz name : science, Score: 80
>
> quiz name : maths, Score : 85
>
> student name : joe
>
> Quiz name : science, Score 60

My code is all over the place at the moment but ill post what I have.

This is the main

---

```
package Student_Quizes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static student.student_main.print;

public class Student_quizes_main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean addStudents = true;
        addStudent();

    }

    public static void addStudent() {

        ArrayList<Student_Quizes> students = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("add student");
        String studentName;
        String Continue;
        int quizScore;
        String quizName;

        boolean addStudents = true;
        boolean addQuiz = true;

        while (addStudents) {

            System.out.println("Student Name");
            studentName = in.next();

            while (addQuiz) {

                System.out.println("Quiz Name");
                quizName = in.next();
                System.out.println("average Score");
                quizScore = in.nextInt();
                students.add(new Student_Quizes(quizName, quizScore));

                System.out.println("Add another Quiz Y/N");
                Continue = in.next();

                if (Continue.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    addQuiz = false;
                }

            }

            System.out.println("Add another Student Y/N");
            Continue = in.next();

            if (!Continue.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

                addQuiz = true;
            } else {
                addStudents = false;
            }

        }

        print(students);

    }

}
```

this is my classes

---

```
package Student_Quizes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student_Quizes {

    private String studentName;
    private String quizName;
    private int score;
    ArrayList<String> quizNames = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> quizScores = new ArrayList<>();

    public Student_Quizes() {
        studentName = "";
        quizNames.add("");
        quizScores.add(0);
    }

    public Student_Quizes(String studentName, ArrayList QuizNames, ArrayList quizScores) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.quizNames.add(quizName);
        this.quizScores.add(score);

    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Name:\t\t" + this.studentName);
        System.out.println("Quiz Name:\t" + this.quizNames);
        System.out.println("Quiz Score:\t" + this.quizScores);

    }
}
```

**Since then I have reworked my code 
The code i have now**

this is the main

package student;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student_main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create ArrayList of student objects
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();


    String name;

    boolean addStudent = true;
    String Continue;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //loop to add multiple students
    while (addStudent) {

        System.out.println("Student Name");
        name = in.next();

        //calls the method to add student information
        addStudents(name, students);

        System.out.println("Would you like to add another Student? Y/N ");
        Continue = in.next();
        //if user does not type n it will continue
        if (Continue.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            addStudent = false;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(students.toString());
}

public static void addStudents(String name, ArrayList<Student> students) {
    //Parralell arrays for quiz names and quiz scores 
    ArrayList<String> quizNames = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> quizScores = new ArrayList<>();

    boolean addQuiz = true;
    String Continue;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Loop to continue adding quizzes
    while (addQuiz) {

        //Method yo add quiz names and scores
        addQuizNames(quizNames);
        addQuizScores(quizScores);

        System.out.println("Would yo like to add another Quiz? Y/N ");

        Continue = in.next();

        if (Continue.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            addQuiz = false;

            // adds the new student passing the students name and quiz info 
            students.add(new Student(name, quizNames, quizScores));

        }
    }

}

public static void addQuizNames(ArrayList<String> quizNames) {

    String quizName;
    Integer quizScore;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Quiz Name");
    quizName = in.next();
    quizNames.add(quizName);

}

public static void addQuizScores(ArrayList<Integer> quizScores) {

    Integer quizScore;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Quiz Score");
    quizScore = in.nextInt();
    quizScores.add(quizScore);

}
```

}

*The classes* 
package student;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student {

```
private String name;
private static ArrayList<String> quizNames = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<Integer> quizScores = new ArrayList<>();

public Student(String name, ArrayList<String> quizNames, ArrayList<Integer> quizScores) {
    this.name = name;
    Student.quizNames = quizNames;
    Student.quizScores = quizScores;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public static void setQuizNames(ArrayList<String> quizNames) {
    Student.quizNames = quizNames;
}

public static void setQuizScores(ArrayList<Integer> quizScores) {
    Student.quizScores = quizScores;
}

public ArrayList<String> getQuizNames() {
    return quizNames;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getQuizScores() {
    return quizScores;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // adds student info to a formated string
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < quizScores.size(); i++) {
        out.append("\n quiz : ").append(quizNames.get(i)).append("\t\tScore : ").append(quizScores.get(i));
    }
    String finalString = out.toString();
    return "\n\nStudent : " + name + finalString;
}
```

}

*The problem*
The problem i am having now is with the quizNames and QuizScores. I can make many student objects and the students name will be correct for each one but the quiz info will be the same for every student. it uses the quiz info for the last student entered so it basically overwrites the quiz info for every student object.

any input is appreciated thanks everyone :)

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You should never, never, never have parallel array lists, parallel arrays, or parallel any data structure.  What you should do is create a Quiz class with the quiz name and quiz score.  Then, in your Student class, you have **one** list of Quiz instances.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc is totally right. Either you should store the Quiz results in a Student class or create a map in which the keys are the student names and the values are the list of results they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you using [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) collection and [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) constants.
Also the quiz type and the score are closely related data so they should be in a separate class.

To make it simple, please check the code below:

Enum class to store the types of quizes.

```
public enum QuizType {
    SCIENCE, MATHS;
}
```

QuizResult is a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) class only for holding the data about the quiz results.

```
public class QuizResult {
    private QuizType quizType;
    private double score;

    public QuizResult(QuizType quizType, double score) {
        this.quizType = quizType;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public QuizType getQuizType() {
        return quizType;
    }

    public void setQuizType(QuizType quizType) {
        this.quizType = quizType;
    }

    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

StudentQuiz class for the input operations. The comments should explain everything.

```
public class StudentQuiz {

    public StudentQuiz() {
        Map<String, List<QuizResult>> students = processStudentQuizes();
        // Go through the keys of the map (which is the name of students)
        for(String student : students.keySet()) {
            // Get all the quiz results of the student
            List<QuizResult> results = students.get(student);
            System.out.println(student + " ");
            for(QuizResult result : results) {
                // Print the quiz type and the score
                System.out.println(result.getQuizType().name() + " " + result.getScore());
            }
        }
    }

    private Map<String, List<QuizResult>> processStudentQuizes() {
        Map<String, List<QuizResult>> students = new TreeMap<>();

        System.out.println("Add student");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        String answer = null;
        while(!"n".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            System.out.println("Student Name");
            String studentName = s.next();

            System.out.println("Quiz Name");
            String quizName = s.next();

            // Check if the quiz type actually exist
            boolean quizTypeOk = false;
            for(QuizType type : QuizType.values()) {
                if(type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(quizName)) {
                    // We found the quiz type, so we can break from this loop
                    quizTypeOk = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!quizTypeOk) {
                // Quiz type couldn't be found, so print the message and start the while loop again
                System.out.println("No such type of quiz! Please start again!");
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println("Average Score");
            double avgScore = s.nextDouble();

            // Now we can create a QuizResult object from the inputed data
            QuizResult result = new QuizResult(QuizType.valueOf(quizName), avgScore);

            // Check if the student already exist
            if(students.containsKey(studentName)) {
                // Add a new result to the list of results for the already existing student
                students.get(studentName).add(result);
            }
            else {
                // Create a new student in the map with a new results list and put the result into the list
                List<QuizResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
                results.add(result);
                students.put(studentName, results);
            }

            System.out.println("Add another Student Y/N");
            answer = s.next();
        }
        s.close();
        return students;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StudentQuiz();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thats a great help, thanks so much I will be having a proper go at this again tommorow  and i will let you know how i get on, thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

Some quick hint:

```
public class Student_Quizes {
  private String studentName;
  private String quizName; ...
```

is actually a good start, but you get it wrong here:

```
this.quizNames.add(quizName);
this.quizScores.add(score);
```

You see: you want that your class Student_Quizes allows to add the two pieces of information. Thus: you do **not** put anything into your two lists in the constructor. Instead, you add a method like

```
public void addQuizInfo(String name, Integer score) {
  quizNames.add(name);
  quizScores.add(score);
}
```

to your class. And then, you just keep calling this method with the input from the user!

Your problem is basically that you pulled things together "repeatedly". Instead, you should clearly separate things. To make that more clear; already your class names goes in the wrong direction. Call it `Student` ... and then think what properties a student has --- he has a name, and then he has lists with the quizes he worked on.

So, you first create a student object:

```
Student newStudent = new Student(name);
```

and then you use that method I showed above:

```
student.addQuiz(quizname, score);
```

And finally: your code wouldn't even compile. You declared your lists within Student_Quizes to be

```
ArrayList<String>
```

for example. Such a lists **only** takes string. Thus the code you have their to add ... another **list** is simply invalid!

Finally: you should use the "interface" types such as List, Map, and so on as type - you only use the concrete implementation class such as ArrayList for the call to new, like

```
List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you for such a great response, that has cleared allot up for me :)

Comment: Thank you so much for that response, it has cleared allot up for me about everything. I am to tired for tonight but i will be working on this again tommorow so i will let you know how i got on, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

if I understood well the problem, one solution is to create a arraylist of a new object instead of

ArrayList quizNames = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList quizScores = new ArrayList<>();

the new object will have properties quizScores  and quizNames, finally in your class create a list of this new object.